# How to wait for a promise resolution?

Tags: angularjs, promise

I need to wait for a promise resolution.

```
 function myFunction(myService, projectId) {
        var localdata;
        var myDataPromise = myService.getData(projectId);
        myDataPromise.then(function(result) {  
           localdata = result;
        });
        var someResult = someProcess(localdata); // I need to wait for promise resolution.
        return someResult;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I try to clarify my question.
I have the myService service with function which return promise:

```
var getData = function (projectId) {
        return projectResource.getProjectUser({ projectId: projectId }, function (result) {
            return result;
        }).$promise;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **don't** want to return data from a promise!
You **do** want to return a promise in order to "continue" the chain.

The wait you are looking for is the callbacks you attach to the promise.

```
function myFunction($scope, myService) {
    var myDataPromise = myService.getData();

    myDataPromise.then(function(result) {  
       // this is the "wait" your looking for.. 
       $scope.data = result;
       console.log("data.name"+$scope.data.name);
    });

    return myDataPromise; // return the promise
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote invalid example. I need work with local variable.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need a local variable** ...

```
function myFunction(myService) {
    return myService.getData().then(function(result) {  
       return result;
    });
}
```

and your caller would be:

```
myFunction(myService).then(function(result){
    //you can be sure that result is fully computed here
    console.log("Your result " + result);
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried to clarify my question. I need local var

Comment: @Mediator It doesn't change anything to the solution. It's pretty strange to do `.$promise`. Never used it. You should prefer using `$q.defer()` and `defer.resolve(...)`.

Comment: You don't need `.then(function(result) { return result; });` either. Just omit that part.

Comment: Indeed, it's for letting the way to compute the result before returns it.

Comment: @Mik378: That probably would be the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572). If there is a `.$promise` available, use it, don't construct deferreds.

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand your question =( It is my bad english.